# How to select all indexes at once in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following java-script code where, all indexes are selected individually to change their style property. So how can I select all indexes at once to change their style?

```
$("#options input[type=checkbox]")[0].style.marginTop = "2px";
$("#options input[type=checkbox]")[1].style.marginTop = "2px";
$("#options input[type=checkbox]")[2].style.marginTop = "2px";
$("#options input[type=checkbox]")[3].style.marginTop = "2px";
$("#options input[type=checkbox]")[4].style.marginTop = "2px";
$("#options input[type=checkbox]")[5].style.marginTop = "2px";
$("#options input[type=checkbox]")[6].style.marginTop = "2px";
$("#options input[type=checkbox]")[7].style.marginTop = "2px";
$("#options input[type=checkbox]")[8].style.marginTop = "2px";
$("#options input[type=checkbox]")[9].style.marginTop = "2px";
```

Comment: So you are using jQuery, use it... not DOM....

Comment: but what will be the code tho? :P

Comment: Check out his answer. It's succinct and on the point.

Comment: why don't you just use a class?

Comment: Would you want to do it with a loop?

Comment: If you're new to jQuery have a guide browse of the documentation: http://api.jquery.com. You just need to look at the method names and it will give you a good idea of what's possible

Comment: Ya, I'm new to jQuery. BTW, thanks for your suggestion, much appriciated :) @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So do it with [jQuery `css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) since you are clearly using it to select the element

```
$("#options input[type=checkbox]").css("marginTop", "2px");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
$("#options input[type=checkbox]").css("propertyname","value");
```

Basically, what it does is setting a value to the specified css property. Pretty straight forward.